How to use AWS SES Subscription management properly with AWS SDK?
I'm trying to implement marketing email subscription like here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/sending-email-subscription-management.html
I'm trying a minimal example a node lambda function:
Here is my code
import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
const sesClient = new SESClient({ region: "us-east-1" });

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  // Define email parameters
  const params = {
    Source: 'support@validsource.com', // verified in SES
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: [
        'valid-address@gmail.com' // Recipient email address
      ]
    },
    Message: {
      Subject: {
        Data: 'Test HTML Email from AWS SES'
      },
      Body: {
        Html: {
          Data: '<h1>Welcome</h1><p>This is a test HTML email sent using AWS SES from a Lambda function. Click <a href="{{amazonSESUnsubscribeUrl}}">here</a> {{amazonSESUnsubscribeUrl}}</p>'
        }
      },
      Headers: [ 
            { 
               "Name": "List-Unsubscribe",
               "Value": "blah@example.com"
            },
            {
              "Name": "List-Unsubscribe-Post",
              "Value": "https://kjhkjh.com"
            },
             {
              "Name": "ListManagementOptions",
              "Value": true
            }
            
        ],
      ListManagementOptions: {
        ContactListName: 'MarketingEmails', // Specify your contact list name here
        TopicName: 'Topic' // Specify your topic name here
      }
    }
  };

  try {
    // Send the email using SES
    const data = await sesClient.send(new SendEmailCommand(params));
    console.log("Email sent!", data);
    return data; // Return success response
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to send email.", err);
    return err; // Return error response
  }
};

I created the topic via commandline aws sesv2 create-contact-list --cli-input-json file://contact_list.json 
When I test it, I receive an email but the link is not populated (blank instead). I spent a few hours and am at a loss here. Anyone has experience with that?

The solution was to use the Amazon SES API v2. So for this, you will need to update the import statement to the following:
import { SESv2Client, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sesv2";
const sesClient = new SESv2Client({ region: "us-east-1" });

You will also need to update the params object as per new API specification given in the link below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/sesv2/command/SendEmailCommand/
